Cannot use table type in stored procedure
Premise: I have REFERENCES permission and every permission I should have. I am using SQL Server (AZURE) and the sqlcmd utility.
I am trying to create a stored procedure which accepts a list of device ids. For this, I have created a type.
-- Drop the table type if it already exists
IF TYPE_ID(N'schemaname.typename') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TYPE schemaname.typename;
END
GO

CREATE TYPE schemaname.typename AS TABLE
(
    DeviceID varchar(50)
);
GO

This is how the procedure looks
if OBJECT_ID('schemaname.procname',  'P') is not null
begin
    drop procedure schemaname.procname;
end
go

CREATE PROCEDURE schemaname.procname
(
    @FromGroupID BIGINT,
    @ToGroupID BIGINT,
    @DeviceIDs schemaname.typename READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
   ...code
END;

I am getting the error: Cannot find the type 'typename', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. I managed to create a type. The type and procedure are in the same database and same schema. I have all the required permissions. What could be wrong?

Have you tried adding the schema name to the type in the proc definition? @DeviceIDs schema_name.DeviceIDTableType READONLY

In your sample code your table type has a different name than the datatype name you used in your procedure.

everything is the same, It was just an editing problem. The type has been declared with the schema name like this schemaname.typename. I will edit the post now

Post your actual code, as it stands there are variations of your object names. In some places you have schema_name and proc_name then in others schemaname  and procedure-name . It could be something simple like that but as we can only see this sample code it's hard to tell.

@AlanSchofield I apologise for the variations in the sample code. I have corrected them by enforcing the same names. I have already checked many times the code (we are talking about 10 lines maybe) and there are no discrepancies in naming.

As there is not enough room in a comment, I've added a fiddle here. As the fiddle does not support Azure you'll have to copy paste each bit of code into a single script (with GO between each bit). This works fine on non-azure instances, I can't test on Azure but I couldn't immediately see anything that says it should not work. If this works, and you still can't work it out, post the whole of your code.

what happens when you run this:     select * from sys.table_types    . Do you see any rows returned ?

I have tried like this that work for me please try and check
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TestingSP;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'EntityIds')
      DROP TYPE dbo.EntityIds;

CREATE TYPE dbo.EntityIds AS TABLE (EntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestingSP
        @AccountIds dbo.EntityIds READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE #TempMonthlyPermits (
                MonthlyPermitId uniqueidentifier  
            );

            INSERT INTO #TempMonthlyPermits (MonthlyPermitId)
            SELECT Id
            FROM MonthlyPermits
            WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM @AccountIds);

            DELETE FROM MonthlyPermitFees
            WHERE MonthlyPermitId IN (SELECT MonthlyPermitId FROM #TempMonthlyPermits);

            DELETE FROM RecurringChargesHistories
            WHERE MonthlyPermitId IN (SELECT MonthlyPermitId FROM #TempMonthlyPermits);

            DELETE FROM MonthlyPermits
            WHERE Id IN (SELECT MonthlyPermitId FROM #TempMonthlyPermits);

            DELETE FROM MetaData
            WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM @AccountIds);

            DROP TABLE #TempMonthlyPermits;
    END;

